# How can I open simultaneously 2 different GUI built with 2 different visualization toolkits ( VTK and tkinter)?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, vtk

I built a GUI with tkinter and another one with VTK for different needs I had, but now I realised that I can't launch them together and I have to close one to let the other appear. I tried to open the tk window from VTK but I have many problems with a missing package.

I'm new to python, so I apologise if the question is easy. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this related to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268131/python-tkinter-creating-a-window-which-runs-my-custom-code (if yes, I think that there's no good news :( )

Comment: Have you tried threading? You might be able to load one in its own thread.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I learned about threading and multiprocessing. I tried both and I have to say that multiprocessing does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for informing me about such a strong tool.